# Allow every variation of IP (host portion)

Tags: .htaccess, server, ip

I have this configuration:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require ip 123.123.123.123
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

What I want is to allow every IP like this: **123.123.123.***

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. (Response code 500)

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you read the manual entry…? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the answer is to use

```
123.123.123
```

as stated in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#:%7E:text=address-,require%20ip%2010.1,-Require).